# Capturing the return value after calling endpoints

Tags: rest, api, http, endpoint

I have a set of endpoints built. i want to capture the return value of whichever 3rd party service calls my endpoint.

Can anyone suggest me how to do it?

Comment: Which server technology are you using? Java, Python, or Node.js etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a database connection, you can insert every requests return value to a table.

Comment: i have a database connection but how do we capture the return of 3rd party service in our end point ?

Comment: It you could insert the main function which generates the return value for just one of your endpoints, it will be more easy to explain.